# "Classic" array in php

Tags: php, arrays, list

So, I'm starting a new project and working with php for the first time.

I get that the average definition and functioning of arrays in php is actually pretty much a namevalue combo.

Is there some syntax, API, or other terminology for just a simple list of items?

I.e. inserting something like `['example','example2','example3','example4']` that I can just call based off their index position of the array, without having to go in and modify the syntax to include `0 => 'example'`, etc...

This is a very shortlived array so im not worried about long term accessibility

Comment: Thanks all for the clarifications!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php arrays are simple to use. You can insert into an array like:

```
$array=array('a','b','c'.....);
```

Or

```
$array[]="a";
$array[]="b";
$array[]="c";
```

or

```
array_push($array, "a");
array_push($array, "b");
array_push($array, "c");
array_push($array, "d");
```

and call them by their index values:

```
$array[0];
```

this will give you `a`

Answer (score 2):

```
$yourArray = array('a','b','c');
```

or

```
$yourArray[] = 'a';
$yourArray[] = 'b';
$yourArray[] = 'c';
```

will get you an array with integer index values instead of an associative one..

Answer (score 2):

You still can use array as "classic" arrays in php, just the way you think.
For example :

```
<?php
$array = array("First", "Second", "Third");
echo $array[1];
?>
```

You can then add different values `<?php $array[] = "Forth"; ?>` and it will be indexed in the order you specified it.

Notice that you can still use it as an associative array :

```
<?php
$array["newValue"] = "Fifth";
$array[1] = "ReplaceTheSecond";
$array[10] = "";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in PHP can either be based on a key, like 0 or "key" => "value", or  values can just be "appended" to the array by using `$array[] = 'value';` .

So:

```
$mine = array();
$mine[] = 'test';
$mine[] = 'test2';
echo $mine[0];
```

Would produce 'test';

**Haven't tested the code.**